# Red flowering climber ID

Tags: species-identification, botany, flowers

Here's another climber from the same garden in [Araku Valley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Araku_Valley)

[image: red flower]

[image: leaves and buds]

So what is this climber?

Does it have any economical uses?

Answer (score 1):

It's an Ipomea also known as a Morning Glory. There are 600 species of Ipomea including the sweet potato. There are [many colors](https://www.google.com/search?q=Ipomoea%20mixed&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwiS3Y-ijpjtAhUYNxoKHS-HDOsQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=Ipomoea%20mixed&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzIECCMQJzICCAAyBAgAEBg6BggAEAgQHjoECAAQHlCPaVicbWCZbmgAcAB4AIABYogByQOSAQE1mAEAoAEBqgELZ3dzLXdpei1pbWfAAQE&sclient=img&ei=b2C7X9LpOJjuaK-OstgO&bih=838&biw=1585#imgrc=Sr06uf-SVjbYoM) of mixed Ipomea, your one is probably a fairly random hybrid. It is perhaps most similar to Ipomoea Rubriflora and [Ipomea Coccinea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ipomoea_coccinea):

[image]